# html5 video does not work with loop and autoplay

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4

I put a simple video on my website:
https://wanapix.es/#wanapixbrand

With this code:

```
<video class="responsive-html-video" autoplay loop>
                <source src="{{ FuImg::asset('img/wanapixvideo.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
```

And it's strange because it doesn't work. At least in my Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your website, the video is playing and works fine on my browser. Make sure your browser settings are right. You can also add  if the problem persists. I also recommend adding controls too.

```html
<video controls width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```